# Make 2 SQL queries in 1?

Tags: php, sql

I have this code below, it's a counter.
it counts how many items are in the list,
if the sql position IS NOT greater than the total items in the list, it increments the position of the counter, if it's greater, it sets to 0 and it keeps going until repeat again and again..

what i'd like to know, if it's possible to make this code below in one single sql query.
because this code runs 2 sql queries each time it is executed, one to get the position, and one to increment or set counter to 0.

```
// Get Position
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE id=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        
        $position = $row['position'];
      
        if ($row["position"] < count($domains) - 1) {

            // Increment
            $sql = "UPDATE $table SET position=position+1 WHERE id=1";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {
              echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
            }

        } else {

            // Set position to 0
            $sql = "UPDATE $table SET position=0 WHERE id=1";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {
              echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
            }
        }

    }

} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: This code sets the position number according to the order in which MySQL returns the rows. Without an ORDER BY clause there's no guarantee that the rows will be returned in the same order every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` clause that sets `position` to different values depending on its current value:

```sql
UPDATE `$table` SET position = (CASE WHEN position <= $domains THEN position + 1
                                ELSE 0
                                END)
WHERE id = 1
```

When the above statement is executed once with `$domains` set to 4, the values change as follows:

```
+------+----------+
| id   | position |
+------+----------+
|    1 |   1 -> 2 |
|    1 |   2 -> 3 |
|    1 |   3 -> 4 |
|    1 |   4 -> 5 |
|    1 |   5 -> 0 |
|    1 |   6 -> 0 |
|    1 |   7 -> 0 |
+------+----------+
```